# git pull request - как правильно с ними работать?

Tags: git

Работа в команде, я работаю над одними и теми же файлами.Но поскольку реализовываю разные фичи - нужно создавать на каждую отдельный pull request.
Алгоритм такой:
Обновляю master, создаю свою ветку (feature1), делаю фичу, создаю pull request, жду одобрения, и объединяю свою feature1 в master.

Но, поскольку одобрение происходит долго, и мне не хочется терять времени, как следует правильно поступать?
до того, как PR ещё не одобрен, создаю новую ветку feature2, не из мастера, а из feature1. Аналогично работаю, в итоге пушу изменения на сервер. 
Теперь создавать новый PR, не зависимо от одобрения первого? или нужно сначала дождаться одобрения первого, слить его в мастер, слить мастер во вторую ветку, а потом создавать новый PR по feature2 ?
Или можно PR сразу несколько подряд создавать?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно так - на каждую фичу своя ветка. Не будет ничего страшного, если создать 10 pull request, но все они должны быть отбранчеваны от master (или develop - смотрите по политике компании).

Ответвлять ветку от ветки можно, но только в том случае, если новая фича зависит от предыдущей и по другому никак. Но следует понимать, что проверяющий может быть не в курсе этого и будет смотреть второй pull request, который будет включать изменения с первого. А вполне может быть, что первый и не нужен. То есть, проверяющий будет делать лишнюю не нужную работу.

Подсумируем:

- одна фича - одна ветка с мастера(девелопа), один pull request.
- количество pull request ограничено здравым смыслом.
- создать ветку с ветки можно, но только если это связанная функциональность и в этом случае лучше подождать одобрения первого pull request, и только потом делать следующий, возможно, сделав rebase ветки с следующей фичей отностительно нового мастера (что бы упростить проверяющему задачу).

P.S.  в гит не нужно бояться создавать много веток.

Comment: +1. Не забывайте ещё удалять topic-branch'и после слияния.

Comment: Вот-вот, насчет двойной работы для проверяющего. Предположим (а у меня именно так), что я создаю ветки одну из другой. master->feature1->feature2->feature3 и т.д. Не будет ли двойной работы проверяющему, если я дождусь аппрува PR1 (feature1), смержу потом эту ветку в master, потом смержу мастер в feature 2 и потом создам PR2 и т.д. по цепочке.

Comment: Нет, не должно. Но в любом случае, я рекомендую попробовать это на отдельном репозитории и посмотреть. Очень полезно.

Answer (score 1):

Да в этом нет большой проблемы

Пока ребята делают review ветки feature, заходим в нее и делаем rebase
когда видим что новые изменения прилетели в master что бы не допускать конфликты

А вторую ветку ребейзим относительно первой пока ее не смерджили
Как ее смерджатЖ ребейзим относительно master и коммиты первой ветки исчезнут из второй и будет чистый PR

Конечно лучше всего такое не допускать, это самому не очень удобно :(

Как совет еще

- используем Labels на PR, к пример WIP (working in progress) на нашу вторую ветку эту будет индикатором на то что не нужно мерджить
- Используйте Review и отмечайте людей кто ветку смотрит